# How would I get the x and y values of a rectangle?

Tags: collision-detection, p5.js

I'm trying to make some simple collision detection code that detects if the outer edge of a square is inside of a rectangle (so far I am only checking for the right and bottom edge) and I was wondering how exactly I would get the x and y values of a rectangle. I tried using rect.x and rect.y but nothing is showing up. I also tried rect[0] and rect[1] (I got desperate) and that also didn't work.

I checked the documentation and the x and y values are shown as x and y
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntCqZ.png) but that lead to nothing. I tried searching for an answer and checked the Similar questions before typing this just to make sure no one else had the same problem as me but found nothing. Here's the code that checks for a rectangle:

```
function collision(rext){//named it rext so it wouldn't think im trying to make an actual rectangle
  if ((x+20) >= rext.x || (y+20) <=rext.y){
    print(rext.x)
    print(rext.y)
  }

}
```

And here's how I call it:

`collision(rect(0,350,400,50))`

If there is any mention and solution to this somewhere on the internet (or maybe even this site) or if there's a far simpler way to detect collision then I truly apologize but i was not able to find it. Thanks

Comment: `rect()` just draws a rectangle, it's not a rectangle object with properties. Please provide more details about your app and use case, preferably a [mcve] of your code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a Rect class, then use it like this r = new Rect(x,y,w,h). The x and y coordinates may be retrieved by using r.x, r.y as shown in the example below:

```
let r;
let msOver = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 400);
  r = new Rect(135, 130, 200, 100);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  if (
    mouseX > r.x &&
    mouseX < r.x + r.w &&
    mouseY > r.y &&
    mouseY < r.y + r.h
  ) {
    msOver = true;
  } else {
    msOver = false;
  }
  r.display();
}

class Rect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }

  display() {
    if (msOver) {
      fill(0, 255, 0);
    } else {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}
```